# Convert array of intensity points to Markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

So I have this code.

Heat map has already been added but now I need to add the markers for each of the place that has intensity point.

I have the latitude and longitude and also intensity.

I also want to show the data using that marker.

I have this code and I am unable to add marker for each intensity point and display the data.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet HeatMap </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css"
    />
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px"></div>

<script
        src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js">
</script>

<script
        src="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js">
</script>
<script src="2013-earthquake.js"></script>
<script>

    var map = L.map('map').setView([21.7679,78.8718], 10);
    mapLink =
        '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
            maxZoom: 10,
        }).addTo(map);


    var heat = L.heatLayer(quakePoints,{
        radius: 20,
        blur: 50,
        maxZoom: 10,
    }).addTo(map);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my sample data:

```js
var quakePoints = [
    [17.123184,79.208824,1.7345],
    [19.123184,79.208824,1.7345],
    [-41.7349,174.013,2.5696],
    [-41.99,174.1059,2.006],
    [-41.6164,174.1405,1.9665],
    [-41.7005,174.0838,2.3406],
    [-40.3361,174.9797,2.9515],
    [-41.7147,174.1782,3.0804],
    [-41.7154,174.0453,1.8717],
    [-41.623,174.1742,2.2847],
];
```

Comment: No, i want to display intensity points data

Comment: I want to show the intensity of each point

Comment: Wait, you mean you want to display each of the points in your `quakePoints` array as a Marker?

Comment: Yes, Yes. You got me right, totally. I literally confused myself. So, How do i do that?

Comment: @ghybs How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way of adding multiple markers:

```
for (var i = 0; i < quakePoints.length; i++) {
        marker = new L.marker(quakePoints[i])
            .bindPopup(quakepoints[i][2])
            .addTo(map);
    }
```

Comment: It worked, Thanks. But i need to display the data present in that array too.

Comment: I've added code to my answer to create a popup on each marker with the 3rd element of your array. Is that what you meant? I'm sure you can adjust the code if not.

Comment: It isn't working. There are no pop ups. The functionality of the code is still the same

Comment: When i remove quakePoints[i][2], The empty pop up appears. May be it is unable to fetch the data when array is used.