# When i click on the marker, the pop up doesn't appear. I get the following error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I tried copy pasting the error and found a resource but i am literally unable to understand what it is.
I'm stuck with this pop up issue, do help me out with it. 
I'm attaching the snippet of my code along with the error that pops out in the console log.

**snippet:**

```
for (var i=0; i<quakePoints.length; i++) {

        var lon = quakePoints[i][1];
        var lat = quakePoints[i][0];
        var popupText = quakePoints[i][2];
        var markerLocation = new L.LatLng(lat, lon);
        var marker = new L.marker(markerLocation);
        marker.bindPopup(popupText).addTo(map);

    }
```

**Error:**

```
leaflet.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
        at e._updateContent (leaflet.js:7)
        at e.update (leaflet.js:7)
        at e.onAdd (leaflet.js:7)
        at e._layerAdd (leaflet.js:6)
        at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:6)
        at e.openPopup (leaflet.js:7)
        at e.openPopup (leaflet.js:7)
        at e.togglePopup (leaflet.js:7)
        at e.fireEvent (leaflet.js:6)
        at e._onMouseClick (leaflet.js:7)
```

**Error- After using leaflet-src.js**

```
leaflet-src.js:4046 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at NewClass._updateContent (leaflet-src.js:4046)
    at NewClass.update (leaflet-src.js:3974)
    at NewClass.onAdd (leaflet-src.js:3899)
    at NewClass._layerAdd (leaflet-src.js:2265)
    at NewClass.addLayer (leaflet-src.js:1723)
    at NewClass.openPopup (leaflet-src.js:4172)
    at NewClass.openPopup (leaflet-src.js:4197)
    at NewClass.togglePopup (leaflet-src.js:4215)
    at NewClass.fireEvent (leaflet-src.js:466)
    at NewClass._onMouseClick (leaflet-src.js:3738)
```

**Edit, Attaching sample data**

```
var quakePoints = [
    [17.123184,79.208824,1.7345],
    [19.123184,76.208824,2.7345],
    [18.123184,69.208824,2.7345],
    [21.123184,70.208824,3.7345],
    [23.123184,72.208824,2.6645],
    [22.123184,77.208824,1.2245],
    [24.123184,85.208824,2.7345],
    [18.123184,78.208824,1.7345],
    [11.123184,89.208824,1.7345]];
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of your `quakePoints` variable?

Comment: @Laiso Done....

Comment: try other way around: `marker.addTo(map).bindPopup(popupText)`

Comment: @Edwin Nope, still same error

Comment: are you sure that the error comes from this part of the code? (map is also not defined in this snippet)

Comment: @Edwin Yes. Code is in my other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650574/convert-array-of-intensity-points-to-markers

Comment: When debugging, please use `leaflet-src.js` instead of `leaflet.js`. That will provide more meaningful stack traces.

Comment: and if you ask multiple questions on stackoverflow please add reference to them - if they are related. We cannot read minds yet or search for other question that can be relevant to yours.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Added the error in the new edit

Comment: @Edwin Sorry for the inconvenience caused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your other question, the `quakePoints` array looks like:

```
var quakePoints = [
    [17.123184,79.208824,1.7345],
    ...
];
```

Which means that `popupText` here ...

```
    var popupText = quakePoints[i][2];
```

...gets the value `1.7345`, but as a *Number*, not as a *String*.

Later, Leaflet is running [this piece of code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/86bb4090c1b1b56165e40b62992750a4e7e2f963/src/layer/DivOverlay.js#L167), with the internal parameter `content` set to the *Number* `1.7345`:

```
    if (typeof content === 'string') {
        node.innerHTML = content;
    } else {
        // snip
        node.appendChild(content);
    }
```

The parameter is *not* a *String*, therefore it tries to handle it as a `HTMLElement`.

Please carefully read the [definition of the `bindPopup` method from the Leaflet API reference](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#layer-bindpopup):

> `bindPopup(<String|HTMLElement|Function|Popup> content, <Popup options> options?)`
>
> Binds a popup to the layer with the passed content and sets up the necessary event listeners. If a `Function` is passed it will receive the layer as the first argument and should return a `String` or `HTMLElement`.

Note how the first parameter to `bindPopup` has to be a `String`, an `HTMLElement`, a `Function` that returns either a `String` or an `HTMLElement`, or an instance of `Popup`. You are passing in a `Number`, which is none of those, so your issue is actually a case of [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in%2C_garbage_out).

The approach here would be to ensure that you're passing a `String`:

e.g. with [`String()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

```
    var popupText = String(quakePoints[i][2]);
```

or e.g. with [`Number.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString):

```
    var popupText = quakePoints[i][2].toString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a genius. The solution is working and thanks for a good explanation too.